# Lowering the type-I seesaw scale without fine-tuning

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

The type-I seesaw mechanism yields the effective neutrino mass $$m_\nu\sim -M_DM_N^{-1}M_D^T.$$ Here, $M_D$ is the Dirac neutrino mass coming from Yukawa coupling of the left-chiral neutrino with the standard model (SM) Higgs and $M_R$ is the mass of the right-chiral neutrino whose scale is not known *a priori*. Without fine-tuning the Yukawa couplings $Y$ in $M_D=Yv$ (where $v=246$ GeV, the VEV of SM higgs) one has $M_D\sim 100$ GeV. Now, if one requires a neutrino mass of the $0.1$ eV, then one must choose $M_N\sim 10^{12}$ GeV.

However, this paper, [below eqn. 2.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08209.pdf), says that

> However, theoretical arguments based on the naturalness of the SM Higgs mass of 125 GeV against radiative effects induced by the neutrino loop suggest the seesaw scale to be below $\sim 10^7$ GeV.

Is this scale of $M_N$ viable without fine-tuning the Yukawa couplings of $M_D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small neutrino masses from a rather small right-handed neutrino mass scale always imply small Yukawa couplings. Note, however that $M_D \sim 100$ GeV assumes Dirac neutrino masses of the order of the *top* quark, by far the largest Yukawa coupling in the Standard Model. If you assume that the neutrino Dirac masses are of the scale of the *lepton* Yukawa couplings, you obtain (for the heaviest state) $M_D \sim 1$ GeV, two orders of magnitude smaller than before.

Since the Dirac mass enters the Seesaw formula quadratically, this lowers the realistic right-handed mass scale by four orders of magnitude. This takes your $10^{12}$GeV down to $10^8$ GeV, very close to the limit you quote.